# Visual basic run-time error 6 (overflow) when running script

Tags: vba, vba7, vba6

Got a mega weird task in college. We are learning Visual Basic in our first year. I am a newbie, I need to output the result of variable y in a TextBox, but I am getting error 6 runtime error (overflow). Please correct the code, what did I do wrong?
[image]

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

x = 2.5
b = 7

a = b ^ 3 + Log(Abs(b))
c = a ^ 2 + Sqr(b)
y = Exp(1) ^ x + 5.8 ^ c


TextBox3.Text = y


End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: What line throws the error? Also, you may need to declare your variables to avoid any issues there.

Comment: @BruceWayne this line - y = Exp(1) ^ x + 5.8 ^ c

Comment: `c`= 118990.327..... and 5.8 raised to that power will overflow.

Comment: @BigBen How can I fix the overflow problem in the c variable? Or maybe I misunderstood the essence of the task, I'm bad at math

Comment: Is this an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? Are you required to use VBA to solve this?

Comment: 5.8 overflows when you attempt to raise it to (just) the 404th power. Not sure if your input data is reasonable here. Or something is off with the provided equations.

Comment: Maybe they made a mistake (typo) and meant `5.8*c`. Let us know if you get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Let's say `Visual Basic` is less 'capable' than `Python`. `VBA`, like `VBScript`, is a piece of `Visual Basic`. Then I'm mostly interested in applying it to `Excel` and don't know half of it. So I know a piece of a piece of a .... I guess that says it all.

Comment: If you are learning VBA you should install the free and fantastic Rubberduck addin for VBA and then pay attention to the Code Inspections.